# grails paginate turning maps into strings

Tags: grails, parameters, pagination

I am trying to create a search action in my grails app that accepts a number of criteria and displays a table (similar to a default index action) of instances that match the criteria.

For search criteria that have many results I would like to use the `paginate` tag:

```
<g:paginate total="${alarmInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
```

By default, this tag forgets the search criteria. I believe that the `params` attribute allows me to add the search parameters to the links that the paginate tag creates.

To encapsulate my search criteria, I've organized them into their own map called `searchParams`.

However, when I try to pass my searchParams to the paginate tag:

```
<g:paginate total="${alarmInstanceCount ?: 0}" params="${[searchParams:searchParams]}"/>
```

my searchParams are turned into a string.

Here is an example of what I mean.

When I first open the search page the controller reports the `params` as follows:

```
[action:index, format:null, controller:alarm, max:10]
null
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

So, since the params map doesn't contain an entry for `searchParams` it comes up as null and has the `NullObject` class. My code handles this case gracefully.

When I enter some text into the `channelName` field the controller reports the `params` as follows:

```
[searchParams.channelName:SWR, searchParams:[channelName:SWR], _action_index:List, _method:PUT, action:index, format:null, controller:alarm, max:10]
[channelName:SWR]
class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap
```

So, now the `params` map has a `searchParams` entry which refers to a `GrailsParameterMap`. This is the desired behaviour, and the controller interprets this correctly.

However, if I click on the first entry in the paginate bar, the controller reports the params as follows:

```
[max:10, searchParams:[channelName:SWR], offset:10, action:index, format:null, controller:alarm]
[channelName:SWR]
class java.lang.String
```

In this third case, the `params` map has a `searchParams` entry that looks correct, but is actually a `String` object. This causes my code to implode with a:

```
No such property: channelName for class: java.lang.String.
```

Is this the expected behaviour of the params attribute of the paginate tag? If so, what is the cleanest way for me to achieve the behaviour I am looking for (i.e. searchParams being passed as a map and not a string to my controller)?

Edit:

Here is the relevant gsp code for my search form:

```
    <g:form url="[action:'index']" method="PUT" >
        <fieldset class="form">
            <div class="fieldcontain">
                <label for="channelName">
                    <g:message code="alarm.channelName.label" default="Channel Name" />

                </label>
                <g:textField name="searchParams.channelName" value="${searchParams?.channelName}"/>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="buttons">
            <g:actionSubmit class="list" action="index" value="${message(code: 'default.button.list.label', default: 'List', args: [entityName])}" />
        </fieldset>
    </g:form>
```

and here is my index action:

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def alarmCriteria = new DetachedCriteria(Alarm)
    def channelInterfaceInstances = ChannelInterface.list();

    if(params.searchParams?.channelName != null && params.searchParams?.channelName != "" && params.searchParams?.channelName != []) {
        alarmCriteria = alarmCriteria.and {
            like("channelName", "%${params.searchParams?.channelName}%")
        }
    }

    def results = alarmCriteria.list(params) {}
    respond results, model:[alarmInstanceCount: results.totalCount, searchParams: params.searchParams]
}
```

Comment: how does you controller load in searchParams?

Comment: I've added my gsp and groovy code to the question.

Comment: The params looks fine, I would suggest a test of using params="[searchParams:searchParams]" to see if it does anything.. The only reason for my suggestion was because I am using  remotePaginate and passing params to it this way....  <util:remotePaginate controller="StreamHistory" action="br" params="[max: max, id:inputid, s:s, order:order, pageSizes:pageSizes, sortby:sortby, offset:offset, ....